# Isn't there an unlockAndSendTransaction function in web3 JavaScript API?

Tags: transactions, web3js, accounts, javascript

I really believe that I saw a function named `unlockAndSendTransaction` on a web3 Javascript API reference page somewhere on Friday 12/09/2016 but today (Monday, 12/12/2016), I am unable to find this function either with a Google search or with a search here on Ethereum StackExchange.

Was I mistaken? Is there such a function, or was I dreaming?
:-)

EDIT: I just found a mention of this function on https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/113  Specifically, `web3.eth.unlockAndSendTransaction` is mentioned in the **Motivation** section. It has other names in the Management personal API - `signAndSendTransaction` and just `sendTransaction` (with optional password param), pre- and post-1.5, respectively. It is the `web3.eth` version that would be useful to me. Will check if it is available in the version that I am working with.

Comment: The following sentence in the **Motivation** section seems to imply that there is such a method implemented in geth (though it is under personal), and also in web3.js : _"Currently we have in geth implemented personal_signAndSendTransaction and web3.js uses the name web3.eth.unlockAndSendTransaction."_ Moreover, in my local workspace, I see that in `/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/methods/personal.js` (version "0.17.0-alpha", there is an `unlockAccountAndSendTransaction` Method defined. Is this not part of the public API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no such function check in geth; it is only a proposition.

this is for the futur in EIP (ethereum improvement protocol).